# CSS pseudo class overrides class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following CSS:

```
input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]) {
    width: 500px;
}

.filterTextbox {
    width: 150px;
}
```

I want to be able to assign filterTextbox class to certain input elements and have textbox be 150px wide. What is happening now, as you can guess, is that first style overrides the .filterTextbox class and I end up having all input textboxes 500px wide.

So, any idea on how to easily resolve this?

Comment: You have to be more specific in the second selector to override styles set on the first selector. In this case that means targeting the tagName, the type and the class -> http://jsfiddle.net/jsz89/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`!important`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/):

```
.filterTextbox {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

The first rule is more specific thus getting higher priority. The `!important` keyword let's the browser know which rule is the desired one, regardless of it's priority.

A better practice however will be not using `!important` as a few suggested in the comments. You can do something like this: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjUpu/))

```
input[type="text"].filterTextbox {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Which will be more specific than the first rule.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer given the circumstances. However, it's worth mentioning - `!important` almost always indicates a deeper design problem.

Comment: `!important` is the hallmark sign of developer failure, being more specific in the selector would be the right answer.

Comment: added another solution without `!important`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option not using !important:

```
input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]):not(.filterTextbox) {
    width: 500px;
}

input.filterTextbox {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Since the upper rule is the 'excluding' one - adding one more exclusion seems more reasonable than using `!important`.

I would probably use classes for the input I'd like to match, or use a more fluid layout altogether.

Comment: Sorry you are right I didn't notice the `:not(.filterTextbox)` part

Answer (score 1):

change

```
.filterTextbox {
    width: 150px;
}
```

to

```
.filterTextbox {
     width: 150px !important;
}
```

That should override anything else being applied to it.